# COMPILATION ERROR : package org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.item does not exist

Tags: java, maven, hyperjaxb

I am using the following dependency in my project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and I see the package org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.item under the jar hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime-060.jar in my maven dependencies for the project. My problem is that Maven complains that the package is not there while building the project. I have removed the jar and tried to rebuild, with no change though. Any help, I am stuck!

Comment: What does this `Maven complains that the package is not there` mean? What about posting a full error log etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Author of Hyperjaxb3 here.

You need `hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime` in the `compile` scope as well. In some cases JAXB structures are not directly compatible with JPA, so HJ3 has to wrap them or otherwise work around incompatibilities. In these cases you may need `hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime`. Maybe not, if your schema is 100% JPA-compilant. Just use the `compile` scope. The `runtime` in the artifact name has nothing to do with Maven scopes.